# Disable saving to iCloud in Mountain Lion

Tags: icloud, macos

Mountain Lion introduced a feature where you can save your documents to iCloud instead of local storage.

[image]

I don't ever see myself using it, is there a way to disable this (but I **don't** want to disable iCloud entirely)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually I found there's a switch in *System Preferences > iCloud > Documents & Data*

[image]

Comment: In Mavericks, in the dialog shown above, next to Documents & data there is a button marked Options which allows you to disable TextEdit only from iCloud. Hooray!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to uncheck Documents & Data from System Preferences, there is also an unexposed preference that disables showing the iCloud-centric open dialog when there are no open windows:

```
defaults write -g NSShowAppCentricOpenPanelInsteadOfUntitledFile -bool false
```

It makes TextEdit create an untitled document and Preview not open any window.

Unlike unchecking Documents & Data, it does not disable using the iCloud-centric open dialog when you for example press command-O.