# How do I remove the iCloud-first behavior in Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos, icloud, data-transfer

In Mountain Lion, I have iCloud activated for Documents. I'd like document-saved-in-the-cloud to be an option, but not the default, as in "if I choose iCloud from the dropdown, save in iCloud, else save in my current folder".

Is it possible?

If it is not, I'll disable the "Documents and Data" switch in System Preferences > iCloud, but it raises the question: how can I list all information currently stored in iCloud, and save them to some real-world folder?

Comment: Anyone have any idea on the last question?  ("how can I list all information currently stored in iCloud, and save them to some real-world folder?")  Or should I ask that as a separate question?

Comment: @D.W. [Access all your iCloud files from the Finder sidebar - Mac OS X Hints](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20120814000425637). There's also another question about [disabling the window shown when opening applications like TextEdit](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/58141/disable-saving-to-icloud-in-mountain-lion).

Comment: @Lri, thanks!  Great stuff!  If I've already saved some files into iCloud, does either of those provide a way to pull them out of iCloud and save them locally?  I couldn't tell from reading them whether there's a way to do that.  (There's a difference between preventatively configuring an app to avoid saving in iCloud in the future, vs finding a way to take a document already saved in iCloud and save it on my local hard disk.)  Also, is there a way to do it in bulk, or do you have to click through each manually, one at a timee?

Comment: @D.W. You can always click them to open them, and then "save them as" local files, but that won't be bulk... Though I guess you could do an AppleScript loop/Automator action.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To change the default to *local* just write in a terminal:

```
defaults write NSGlobalDomain NSDocumentSaveNewDocumentsToCloud -bool false
```

To change back to iCloud first, type:

```
defaults write NSGlobalDomain NSDocumentSaveNewDocumentsToCloud -bool true
```